# cannot use geometry manager pack inside error tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

ı am new tkinter. I want to add a image to my programme. But ı am taking a error:cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid. If ı run this code individual it is working. I can obtain image and programme is working. But if ı run together image and function it is not working.  How can ı fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x900+100+200")
root.title("Converter")
root.configure(background="grey")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
lenghtVal="Lenght"
def store_lenght(sel_lenght):
  global lenghtVal
  lenghtVal=sel_lenght
def call_result(rL,inputn):
 lenght=inputn.get()
 if lenghtVal=="Angström-Milimetre":
    mm=float((float(lenght)*10**-7))
    rL.config(text="% f milimetre" % mm)

 if lenghtVal=="Yard-Metre":
    m=float((float(lenght)*0.9144))
    rL.config(text="% f metre" % m)


 if lenghtVal=="Inch-Metre":      
    m=float((float(lenght)*0.0254))
    rL.config(text="% f metre" % m)

 if lenghtVal=="Mil-Metre":
    km=float((float(lenght)*1.6903))
    rL.config(text="% f kilometre" % km)
 return
numberInput=tk.StringVar()
var=tk.StringVar()
input_label=tk.Label(root,text="Enter",background="white",foreground="black")
input_entry=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=numberInput)
input_label.grid(row=0)
input_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
rLabel=tk.Label(root,text="0.0",background="white")
rLabel.grid(row=4,columnspan=2)
call_result=partial(call_result,rLabel,numberInput)

result_button=tk.Button(root,text="convert",command=call_result,background="white",foreground="black")
result_button.grid(row=2,columnspan=2)
dropdownList=["-Uzunluk Ölçüleri-","Angström-Milimetre","Yard-Metre","Inch-Kilometre","Mil-Metre"]
dropdown=tk.OptionMenu(root,var,*dropdownList,command=store_lenght)
dropdown.grid(row=0,column=2)
var.set(dropdownList[0])

root=Tk()

root.geometry("1255x944")
image=Image.open("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\6.png")
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label=Label(image=photo)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can't mix managers `pack()` and `grid()` inside one window or one widget because both use automatic calculations to orgamnize elements in window/widget and when one manager moves elements then another has to recalculate positions and moves elements and this means that first has to again recalculate elements and moves them, etc. But you can put `frame` and inside `frame` you can use different manager then outside `frame`. OR you have to use only `pack()` or only `grid()` to put all widgets.

Comment: Multiple instances of `Tk()` should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

In tkinter, `.grid()` and `.pack()` cannot be used in the same window. To solve the problem, you have to choose to either use only `.grid` or `.pack()`.

Near the end, you wrote `label.pack()`. Instead, use `label.grid(row=5)` or wherever you want to put your label.

If you still want to use both, you can put all of your widgets that use `.grid()` into a Frame widget. Then, you can pack both frames.

Comment: _"In tkinter, .grid() and .pack() cannot be used in the same window."_ is a false statement when taken literally. They can be used in the same window as long as they aren't both used for widgets that have the same parent. In fact, it's generally considered a best practice to use both in a window, as they each excel at different types of layouts