# Tkinter: why .grid() method giving an error?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, error-handling, graphics

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as rd

number = rd.randint(10,51)
trial = 0
chance = 0

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Guess")
label = tk.Label(window, text="Guess a number that can be anything from '10' to '50', you have 5 chances !!!\n", font=("Arial Bold",20)).pack()

bt = tk.Button(window, text="Enter")
bt.grid(column=3, row=3)

window.geometry('2000x1000')
window.mainloop()
```

Error: `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`

If I try to remove .pack() in 'label', the text doesn't load and still the button remains at (0,0) while there is no error

Comment: Not related to the error, but it's usually wrong to set a variable to the result of `.pack()`. You should set `label` to the `tk.Label` object, and then call `label.pack()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot use geometry manager pack inside error tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880020/cannot-use-geometry-manager-pack-inside-error-tkinter)

Comment: to add to the @Barmar answer: if You don't plan on using the widget afterwards You might as well just do for example `Label(master, **options).pack()` without assigning a variable instead of `var = Label(master, **options).pack()`

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. FWIW, "." is the internal name of the root window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is change label to also use grid instead of pack, I changed the line below:

```
label = tk.Label(window, text="Guess a number that can be anything from '10' to '50', you have 5 chances !!!\n", font=("Arial Bold",20))
label.grid()
```

Comment: why do You asign `Widget().layout_manager()` to a variable? it returns None so the variable is pretty useless.

Comment: @Matiiss Even worse, people chain these to save space presumably and then do `label.something` and get an AttributeError. Happens all the time.

Comment: @Reti43 Yeah I see that all the time too, but if one wants to save space why write variable? (presumably because they don't know it is not necessary). In those cases it is even possible to use a textvariable attribute but then again that is a bit excessive.

Comment: I should have put grid on the second line as in another answer. I put it on the same line because that's how the OP had it. I, too, am learning and I didn't think what would happen if label.something was used later.

Comment: changed to reflect feedback from @Matiiss

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear, you cannot mix between `pack()` and `grid()` inside a container or window. Here you are using `pack()` on the `label` and `grid()` on the `btn`. So change `label` to `grid()`. Or change `bt.grid(..)` to `bt.pack()`.

---

Keep a note, your `label` is `None`, it can cause several errors later, if you plan on reusing the label. So the ideal way is to `grid()`/`pack()` on next line:

```
label = tk.Label(window, text="Guess a number that can be anything from '10' to '50', you have 5 chances !!!\n", font=("Arial Bold",20))
label.pack()
```

And if you don't plan on reusing it, then don't bother giving it a variable name at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either grid or pack, not both. That's what I think from my experience.

> Error: _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
> It says it's managed by pack, so you need to use pack manager "OR" grid manager